# HTML5 Fullscreen API on iframes ? (Facebook)

Tags: facebook, html, fullscreen

I'm trying a few things with the HTML5 fullscreen API, and it seems it doesn't work inside an element of an iframe (I was trying to use that on facebook, and ended up with that conclusion).

Does anyone know a way to make it work even on iframe ? This is essentially because I would like to use fullscreen in facebook apps, so I can have a real fullscreen without having to use flash..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook now supports HTML5 Fullscreen API perfectly

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're asking, then no: Facebook.com cannot be displayed in an iframe.

If you take a look at your Javascript Console in your browser, attempting to bring www.facebook.com into the page with an iframe will give you the error `Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.`

Comment: No, I mean in facebook apps, which are iframes.
But it's the same for any sort of iframes actually.

Comment: Ah, well I wouldn't be surprised if Facebook parsed out full-screen functionality out of apps on canvas pages within facebook.com. But I can't be of any more help, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Ok the answer was simple :

webkitallowfullscreen changing depending on the browser, etc.

BUT :

- Facebook doesn't support it yet.
- They are taking it into consideration
- See this : https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/436162913102704?browse=search_5046c9a1032a58d19137888